# Implementation of having count with group by in java 8

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I am looking for an implementation of group by, having and then filter based on count in lambda expressions.

```
select COUNT(employee_id), department_id  from employee
GROUP BY department_id
HAVING COUNT(employee_id) > 1
```

Is there any simple implementation of achieving this using lambda expressions.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can combine the `groupingBy` collector, with `counting()` and `collectingAndThen`:

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.collectingAndThen;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.counting;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy;

...

Map<Long, Long> map = 
    employees.stream()
             .collect(collectingAndThen(groupingBy(Employee::getDeptId, counting()), 
                                        m -> { m.values().removeIf(v -> v <= 1L); return m; }));
```

Note that here is no guarantee on the mutability of the map returned by `groupingBy`, so you can use the overloaded version and supply a concrete mutable instance if you want.